# How can I resolve this error? (LINQ to XML)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-xml

In my project I'm using Entity Framework, I've got a problem in ExamProduced entity, to be especific in Quantify property.

In my database Quantify property is tinyint datatype, and when VS imported it, it became in byte. VS is notifying me an error that it's unknown for me.

Here are the images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you tried with Attribute("Foo").Value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's no explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `byte`. You'd probably be okay with:

```
Quantify = (byte) (int) objective.Attribute("Quantify")
```

The `(int)` part will apply the [explicit `XAttribute` to `int` conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993.aspx); the `(byte)` part will perform a narrowing `int` to `byte` conversion. You may want to make this `checked` so that you'll get an exception if the attribute is "500" for example.